# AJAX and XML mutiple choice quiz - choices loading to same var

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml

I'm having trouble getting the choices getting separated on different lines and I am not sure why and have not been able to figure out why

XML:

```
<q>
    <qNum>1</qNum>
    <qText>What is the side of a hammer called?</qText>
    <choice>Hammer</choice>
    <choice>Face</choice>
    <choice>Side of the hammer</choice>
    <choice>The check</choice>
</q>
```

AJAX:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

$.get('quiz.xml', function (d){

    var html;

    var title = $(d).find('title').text();
    var desc = $(d).find('description').text();
    html = '<div><h1>'+title+'</h1><br><h3>'+desc+'</h3><br></div>';
    $('#1').append(html);

    $(d).find('q').each(function(index, element) {

        var $q = $(this);
        var qNum = $q.find('qNum').text();
        var qText = $q.find('qText').text();
        var html2 = '<div><p>'+qText+'</p>';

        $q.find('choice').each(function(index, element) {
            var choice = $q.find('choice').text();
            html2 += '<input type="radio" name="q'+qNum+'" class="choice" value="'+choice+'" /><label class="choice">'+choice+'</label><br>';
        });

        $('#1').append($(html2)); 

    });

});
```

});

All the choices will be added to the var every time and i cant figure out how to break them up with keeping the same tag name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change it to

```
    var choice = element.textContent;
```

Comment: While this code is correct, and helped the OP, adding some explanation of *why* this code answers the question will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [answer] for more information.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I will keep that in mind the next time.

Answer (score 0):

You should change

```
var choice = $q.find('choice').text();
```

to

```
var choice = element.text();
```

I think. What it looks like is that for each choice, you select all the choices with `$q.find('choice')`, whereas you only want the choice you are currently iterating over, which is in `element`.

Comment: Im not sure what index and element are actually used for as its what is defaulted there when you add the ".each" function but it doesnt show any values if i change it to what you suggested thank you though